# Admob interstitial ad still open when user comes back from clicking it

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

When a user clicks an interstitial ad, the browser will open or whatever. When he navigates back to my app, the interstitial ad is still open and he has to close it.

How can I prevent an interstitial ad from still being displayed after the user clicked it and navigates back to my app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following to your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:noHistory="true"/>
```

What `noHistory` does:

> Whether or not the activity should be removed from the activity stack and finished (its finish() method called) when the user navigates away from it and it's no longer visible on screen — "true" if it should be finished, and "false" if not. The default value is "false".
>
> A value of "true" means that the activity will not leave a historical
>   trace. It will not remain in the activity stack for the task, so the
>   user will not be able to return to it. In this case,
>   onActivityResult() is never called if you start another activity for a
>   result from this activity.

Source: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist